# dnode working along nodejs on windows 8 error

Tags: python, node.js, dnode

i have been trying to get dnode to install from this link

http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/

i tried

```
npm install dnode
```

i gave me the following error.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (E:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\n
pm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:118:14)
```

could someone plz assist me with this issue with appropriate commands :)

much regards guys

Answer (score 0):

Do you have python installed?  Is it in your path?

```
which python
```

If not you can set the PYTHON environment variable specifically so that gyp can find it.

```
export PYTHON=/Path/To/python
```

Comment: i have it working with xampp but not seem to work with it...will this release work     http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/               the Windows x86 MSI Installer (2.7.5) (sig)

Comment: I did a quick google check, can't find required version.  It will probably be okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the [weak](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-weak) module that dnode uses, which is a native module and needs to be compiled with node-gyp.  You are likely to have other problems, not just having Python available.   I've had problems installing dnode on windows too.

However, weak is [now an optional module in dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode/commit/34d1c9aa9696f13bdf8fb99d9d039367ad873f90).  Its not recommended to use dnode without weak for long running or very heavily used connections without weak, as its a potential memory leak - but it is now usable.